# RMI - work in the same machine, not in LAN

Tags: java, networking, rmi, lan, rmiregistry

I am trying to establish two-communication between one server and two clients. This works very well when all programs run on the same machine but it doesn't work when I try using LAN network.
I got the error :

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.24; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Here is the server code :

```
public class Server{
private Game partie; // The class Game extends UnicastRemoteObject and implements ServerInterface


public Server() throws RemoteException {
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.1.24");
    partie = new Game();
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    try{
        Naming.rebind("Server", partie);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String argv[]) throws RemoteException{
    new Server();
}
}
```

Here is the constructor of the client code :

```
public Client(String aName, String aServerAdress) throws RemoteException {
    super();
    name = aName;
    ServerAdress = aServerAdress; //  = "192.168.1.24"
    theRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ServerAdress);

    try {
        serverInterface = (ServerInterface) theRegistry.lookup("Server");
    } catch (NotBoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    try {
        theRegistry.bind(name, this); // For two-way communication
    } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    serverInterface.registerClient(name);
}
```

Where registerClient(String name) code is approximately (in Game class) :

```
cd_client = (ClientInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/" + name);
```

All firewalls are disabled.

I have been working on this problems for many hours and I have still not found  what is wrong. I would really appreciate if you could help me a bit.
Thank you

Comment: Local network and LAN? how do you differentiate these?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 & 192.168.1.24 are not (necessarily) the same machine (as far as your networking code is concerned).  Make your references consistent.

Comment: 192.168.1.24 is the adress of the machine I use to run the server application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all occurances of 127.0.0.1 (except registry binding) to your LAN IP address (192.168.1.24 in your case)

127.0.0.1 is a [Loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) address:

> "Loopback (loop-back) describes ways of routing electronic signals,
>   digital data streams, or flows of items from their originating
>   facility back to the receiving end of the source without intentional
>   processing or modification. This is primarily a means of testing the
>   transmission or transportation infrastructure."
>   -- from Wikipedia

Comment: Thank you, this works. But now I have another error :
`java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.Registry.rebind disallowed; origin /192.168.1.56 is non-local host`.
The origin is `theRegistry.bind(name, this)` in the client code. Can I register the client on the registry (which is on the server) ? So the server can call methods on the client.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820719/using-single-rmi-registry it seem that you actually should use loopback for registry binding. Edited my answer aswell

Comment: I added the client registry binding in the registerClient method and it works well, thank you for your help.